# Python: Can't use the command python

Tags: python, windows, installation

I want to install summon-module on windows 7.
I tried

```
python setup.py install
```

but cmd doesn't know the command "python".

I also set the path correctly.
What is the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If You 'set the path correctly' there probably wouldn't be a problem. Give Your PATH variable here.

Comment: The programm is called setup.py or setup-windows.py

Comment: Oh my god, it isn't in the path.

Comment: I set the path in the environment variables.

Comment: when I restart my path is gone again. :(

Comment: @kame: Please stop commenting on your own question.  Please delete your comments.  Please UPDATE the question with the information, so that everything we need to know is in the question.  Please stop adding comments to a question which you own and can fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the directory with the python.exe to your path via Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment Variables.  Then scroll through the System variables listed in the lower part of the screen, highlight "Path", and click edit.  **Add** (don't replace!) the directory to that variable, probably at the end.  Make sure there's a semi-colon (';')between it and the entries in front of and (if appropriate) behind it; I recommend putting a semi-colon at the end even if it's the last value.  Once you've done this, click the Ok button on the environment variables dialog box and start a new commend shell.  You can type path at the prompt to get the path displayed so you can confirm that the python directory has been added.

Answer (score 4):

`PATH` needs to point to the directory your python.exe is in, or it needs to be in the current directory, or you need to specify the full path.

`PYTHONPATH` needs to point to the directory your setup.py is in, or it needs to be in the current directory, or you need to specify the full path.

Comment: Dammit too: I set the pythonpath, but nothing changes. :)

Comment: I found the problem. There where two different pythonpath!!! personal variables path and system variables path. :)

Answer (score 0):

on windows it is python.exe and you need the path to the executable added to your environment or to use the fully qualified path